# JDBCTemplate not giving appropriate result with parameters

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to run a SQL in Oracle. It runs absolutely fine when run in the Oracle database, while passing the params in SQL developer, but it gives a nested exception while using the `JdbcTemplate`

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

I am passing the params through a map as given below.

```
select to_char(c.created_dt, :GROUP_FORMAT) as point
      ,count(*) as CNT
  from tableA c
 where trunc(c.created_dt) >= to_date(:START_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
   and trunc(c.created_dt) <= to_date(:END_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
 group by to_char(c.created_dt, :GROUP_FORMAT)

return jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
         ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
           .put("GROUP_FORMAT", groupFormat)
           .put("END_DATE", Date.valueOf(endDate))                                                                  
           .put("START_DATE", Date.valueOf(startDate))
           .build(), (rs, rowNum) -> {
             ClassToMap data = ClassToMap.builder().point(rs.getString(1)).count(rs.getInt(2)).build();
             return data;});
```

The issue is mainly with the `GROUP_FORMAT` parameter, have verified hard-coding the `GROUP_FORMAT` and it works fine. The values of `GROUP_FORMAT` passed will be `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYYYMM'`

Expect the output to be an array of `ClassToMap` objects.

Comment: I posted a question about `jdbcTemplate` a while back and someone responded `jpa`? is much easier to work with.

Comment: `:GROUP_FORMAT` is an Oracle _bind variable_. Can `JdbcTemplate` handle this? My guess is that it is not being replaced with the actual value. Can you verify that? Perhaps you can replace `:GROUP_FORMAT` with the `?` place holder recognized by JDBC?

Comment: @Abra changing :GROUP_FORMAT didn't help.

Comment: Did you verify that in the string passed to the database, `:GROUP_FORMAT` is replaced by its value? If you replaced `:GROUP_FORMAT` with `?`, did you verify that `?` is being replaced by a relevant value?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941034/is-it-possible-to-use-group-by-with-bind-variables someone (after 8 years!) suggested using OraclePreparedStatement

Comment: @Abra, the issue is same as the one as shared by racraman.

Comment: @racraman Thanks for pulling up the post, that answered everything on why we are seeing the issue.

Comment: Well, with absolutely zero experience in `JdbcTemplate` and _Spring_, I was on the right track. You needed to replace `:GROUP_BY` with `?`. The only thing I missed - and that would be due to my lack of `JdbcTemplate` experience - was to use `?` once only, and not twice.

Comment: @Abra, absolutely , no doubt that your input was of some great insights!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JdbcTemplate does not make just string concatenation but a piece of wrapping for parameters. So, you won't be able to pass them to 'synthetic' expressions like 'to_char'.
Alternatively you can group by the same not formatted column which should give you the same result hopefully.

I've tested it working on the following code:

```
String groupFormat = "YYYYMMDD";

String sql = "select c.created_dt, to_char(c.created_dt, :groupFormat) as point" + 
        "      ,count(*) as CNT" + 
        "  from your_table c" + 
        " group by c.created_dt";

MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
namedParameters.addValue("groupFormat", groupFormat);

dbSelector.gssNamedJdbcTemplate().query(sql, namedParameters, rs -> {
    logger.info(rs.getString(1));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was same as shared by racraman in the comments. Changing the SQL to accept the param in only one place resolved the issue